# Php email validation (nothing happend)

Tags: php

Can someone tell me why this is not working to validate this email.

```
if (filter_var($_POST['Email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    echo 'Nope';
}
```

---

```
<div class="join input-group">
    <a class="join_topic">Email *</a>
    <input type="text" name="Email" id="Email"  value="<?php echo escape(Input::get('Email')); ?>" class="form-control">
</div>
```

When i press register nothing happend when i type "123" as the email..

Comment: You're using it the other way around, you echo 'Nope' when filter_var() returns the passed filtered data, not when it fails (as in `123`)

Comment: According to the [manual](http://www.php.net/filter_var): "*Returns the filtered data, or **FALSE if the filter fails**.*"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"123" is not a valid email address by the specifications of the FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL filter which is why you're not seeing a response. Enter "123@foo.com" and it should work fine. You might also want to and an else conditional while you're at it.

```
if (filter_var($_POST['Email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
  echo 'Valid Email';
}else{
  echo 'Not Valid';
}
```

Comment: is it possible to do that it does not say Not Valid when i havent writen in something? @halabuda

Comment: an empty email input will also be filtered as invalid. you can change the output of either condition to anything you like, put in your own statements to do something useful, or do nothing at all.

Answer (score 1):

According to it's [manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php), `filter_var` will return false if the validation fails or the filtered data on success. You if statement should look like this:

```
if (filter_var($_POST['Email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === FALSE) {
    echo 'Nope';
}
```